# Run commands after unlocking X screen (KDE)

Tags: x11, kde, screensaver, screen-lock

When I leave work, I lock my machine with ctrl + l  to lock the screen. When I come back, I always forget to log into jabber. Is there a way to run a command after the screen is unlocked? This is in KDE. I'm not sure if the locking mechanism is an X feature or a KDE feature, so I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 2):

I had a desire to make banshee (the Gnome music player) pause/unpause when the screen was locked/unlocked.  I found a ticket in the banshee launchpad project:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/banshee/+bug/237687

Someone had created a script which would notice (via DBus) if the screen was (un)locked and would trigger banshee to (un)pause.  I added a small tweak to this script and have been using it for a while.  I added my updated copy to that ticket.

Now I know this isn't exactly what you want to do.  But you could probably take that python script (which is already detecting screen locks/unlocks) and alter it slightly to do what you would like to do.  It is also my understanding that the KDE screensaver supports the same DBus interface as the gnome screensaver.  It seems like the best documentation for the KDE side of things is here:

http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kde-workspace.git&a=blob&f=krunner/screensaver/saverengine.h

Good luck!

Comment: So is the lock screen considered a screen saver?

Comment: Yeah.  I mean, I'm pretty sure they both produce the same event in DBus.

Comment: For KDE users, substitute "org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver"  for the Gnome specific string on the second last line of the script.

Answer (score 2):

For the XScreenSaver the solution is `xscreensaver-command -watch`

`man xscreensaver-command` contains an example Perl script to handle various screensaver and screen lock events, like BLANK, LOCK, UNBLANK etc.

Here it is - the example turning sound off and on with the screensaver:

```
       #!/usr/bin/perl

       my $blanked = 0;
       open (IN, "xscreensaver-command -watch |");
       while (<IN>) {
           if (m/^(BLANK|LOCK)/) {
               if (!$blanked) {
                   system "sound-off";
                   $blanked = 1;
               }
           } elsif (m/^UNBLANK/) {
               system "sound-on";
               $blanked = 0;
           }
       }
```

Not sure if KDE uses XScreenSaver though.

Answer (score 0):

An updated script to improve mark-drago's answer:

```py
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
import os

def screensaver_changed(state):
  """This method is called when the screensaver starts/stops """
  screensaver = session_bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver', '/ScreenSaver')
  active = screensaver.GetActive()
  print("ScreenSaver is " + ("on" if active else "off"))
  if not active:
    os.system("xkbcomp ~/.Xkeymap :0")

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
session_bus.add_signal_receiver(screensaver_changed,'ActiveChanged','org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver')


from gi.repository import GLib

loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```