# Xorg configuration hook for unblank screen

Tags: x11, xorg, screensaver

Is is possible to execute a command automatically when X comes out of a power saving screen blank?  I.e., something that would be triggered when I hit a key/move the mouse to power up the display again?

Comment: I think if same thing existed, you , all of community , i all of we, know it.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/run-commands-after-unlocking-x-screen-kde mentions triggers for screensaver programs, which isn't what you're asking about but is close enough for some scenarios.

Comment: I think all displayed windows will receive an Expose event, so you should be able to do that by placing a 1x1 permanently on top somewhere, if losing one pixel of screen estate is acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X11 has a screensaver extension which offers a notification  API for the blanking and unblanking of the display (including dpms events). Tools like `xssstart` (https://github.com/unixdj/xssstart) use this API to run a command as soon as the screen is blanking. But you also can catch the 'unblank' event to run a command then.

All you have to do is change the event it triggers in line 90 (https://github.com/unixdj/xssstart/blob/master/xssstart.c#L90)

from `state == ScreenSaverOn` to `state == ScreenSaverOff`

and you have your `xssstop` tool

Comment: I no longer have a need to do this, but I am not sure this would work unless *screen blanking* is synonymous with *screen saver* -- which I don't think it is.  As per the question: "when X comes out of a power saving screen blank"; this is a potential of modern monitors which replaced the need for screen savers.

Comment: @goldilocks xssstart uses the X11 screensaver extension. So you definitely get these events. I already tried this with 'blanking' and also 'dpms' which powers down the display.

Comment: I'll take your word for it ;) It would be good if you made that explicit in the body of the answer.